# Can't turn off debug logging for Wiremock

Tags: logging, spring-boot, wiremock

I'm using Wiremock for my tests in a Spring Boot app. I can't seem to get the logging to not output all debug logs, which makes my test runs very verbose.

I see it use SLF4J on startup:

> DEBUG wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging to Logger[wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] via wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog

But trying to configure it in my application.properties via,

> logging.level.wiremock.org.eclipse=WARN

Has no effect, I've also setup

> logging.level.com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock=WARN

But again, no effect. Since I'm using `spring-boot-starter-web` which uses `spring-boot-starter-logging`, [which if I understand correctly uses Logback](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html), I've also tried configuring this in `logback-spring.xml`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <logger name="wiremock.org.eclipse" level="INFO"/>
</configuration>
```

Again, nothing I do stops Wiremock from logging debug level. What am I missing?

Answer (score 24):

Ok Ive just had this problem and finally solved it.
There are 3 different loggers you need to configure

- the eclipse logger at `wiremock.org.eclipse`
- the wiremock notifier at `WireMock`
- the serverlet logger at `"/"` or what ever your logger is located at.
- the wiremock code logging at `com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock`

Ive found that the bootstrap.yml does not affect these loggers so you need to put them in your `logback-test.xml` in your /src/test/resources folder

with the following entries.

```
<!-- Turning down the wiremock logging -->
<logger name="com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="wiremock.org" level="ERROR"/>
<logger name="WireMock" level="WARN"/>
<!-- wiremock has per endpoint servlet logging -->
<logger name="/" level="WARN"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to change `logging.level.root`; `INFO` will make WireMock to be verbose enough to check stub matching while `WARN` will prevent it.

This has its side effect, of course; this affects all logging; but is dirty and quick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this programmatically and you are using SLF4J with Logback (the default in Spring Boot 2.2), just do this:

```
((LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory()).getLogger("wiremock").setLevel(Level.OFF);
((LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory()).getLogger("WireMock").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

(Using WireMock 2.25)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Spring Boot, you could simply add this configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75626043/3263041